# get nested json value using translateService.get() of ngx-translate

Tags: ngx-translate

I have a translation file with nested translations :

```
...
"LANG": {
    "Dutch": "Néerlandais",
    "English": "Anglais",
    "French": "Français"
},
...
```

I'm trying to retreive my translations using TranslateService :

```
this.translate.get(['LANG.French', 'LANG.English', 'LANG.Dutch'])
  .subscribe((translations) => {
    console.log(translations.LANG.French);
});
```

I thought the translations object would look like this :

```
translations : {
    LANG : {
        "Dutch": "Néerlandais",
        "English": "Anglais",
        "French": "Français"
    }
}
```

But in fact it looks like this :

```
translations : {
    LANG.Dutch : "Néerlandais",
    LANG.English: "Anglais",
    LANG.French: "Français"
}
```

And console.log(translations.LANG.French) fails because translations.LANG is undefined.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone come here :

`this.translate.get(['LANG'])
     .subscribe((translations) => {
    console.log(translations.LANG.French);
});`

It will work but will retreive the whole object LANG. Thus it may contain some useless properties.